# iPhone is there a way to analyze timestamps of all photos on the camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, timestamp, photo-gallery

I have ~3200 photos on my iPhone over 2 years and would like to create an app that analyzes and plots when I took these pictures (ex: I was very actively photographing for a week, and then stopped). **Is there a way to do bulk processing of camera roll photos on iPhone(with user permission) to extract timestamps of photos?**

I think if I back up my photos to my mac with the "image capture" app, I can do this kind of metric analysis with a Mac app, but the import process would take hours and I'm looking for something simpler.

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary may be a good start for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> An instance of ALAssetsLibrary provides access to the videos and
>   photos that are under the control of the Photos application.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotosByLocation/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010136) is sample application PhotosByLocationn.

> Demonstrates how to use the AssetsLibrary APIs to provide a custom
>   image picking UI. The user experience is centered around the idea of
>   using the assets location and time metadata as a basis for certain
>   features.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the [Assets Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html) for this.

This fill allow you acces to the image on the users device.